# What would be the best tool for me to use for this project idea?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, content-management-system

I'm going to make a website where users (including myself) can create programming tutorials with full pictures to guide anyone who needs help for free.

Common tasks, like configuring the Web.Config, creating a database connection in C#/Java/Python etc.

I'm planning on using ASP.Net MVC2.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are there specific features that you want to implement which something like a blog engine does not provide?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are comfortable with php based cms.But if you have the time and plan on doing some work before starting the project, I would suggest going for a php based cms. A few of them are Drupal, Joomla, Wordpress.